# node.js / express app with cwe-352 vulnerability

Tags: node.js, express, security

I have a simple Node.js / Express app, which receives a cwe-352 vulnerability warning at the following line of code that creates the instance of Express:

```
const app = express();
```

I have researched this issue and found nothing thus far, which indicates that this particular line of code is a potential vulnerability.

Any idea as to why this line of code would raise this particular security concern and how could it be resolved?

https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/352.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: following for solution.